# Codeigniter Form Validation opening blank page

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, model-view-controller

I am following a tutorial on how to create a login system using Codeigniter.

I have created the following form in my view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<body>

<div class="container">

    <h1>Login</h1>

<?php

    echo form_open('welcome/login_validation');

    echo validation_errors();


    echo form_label('Email: ');
    echo form_input('email'); //form_input(name,value)

    echo '<br />';

    echo form_label('Password: ');
    echo form_password('password');

    echo '<br />';

    echo form_submit('login_submit', 'Login'); //form_submit(name,value)


    echo form_close();


?>
</div>


</body>

</html>
```

But when I click the submit button, on google chrome, it opens a blank page with "about:blank" in the address bar.

In FireFox it has the correct address "...welcome/form_validation" but comes up with the following message:

"This address is restricted
This address uses a network port which is normally used for purposes other than Web browsing. Firefox has canceled the request for your protection."

On Microsoft Edge, it just stays at the page with the form.

Here is my Controller:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

/**
 * Index Page for this controller.
 *
 * Maps to the following URL
 *      http://example.com/index.php/welcome
 *  - or -
 *      http://example.com/index.php/welcome/index
 *  - or -
 * Since this controller is set as the default controller in
 * config/routes.php, it's displayed at http://example.com/
 *
 * So any other public methods not prefixed with an underscore will
 * map to /index.php/welcome/<method_name>
 * @see http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html
 */
public function index()
{
    $this->login();
}

public function login()
{
    $this->load->view('login');
}

public function login_validation()
{

   $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|md5');


    if($this->form_validation->run()){

        redirect('main/members');


    } else{

        $this->load->view('login');


    }

}


public function members()
{

    $this->load->view('users');



}

}
```

Any help is appreciated. If you need anymore info, let me know and I will post it.

Thanks

Edit: I am using codeigniter 3.0.3

Comment: Change `echo form_open('welcome/form_validation');` to `echo form_open('welcome/login_validation');` no such `form_validation` method in your controller exist.

Comment: @Saty I changed that, but am Still getting the same problem.

Comment: @Ddrossi93 your form_open proably adds an index.php if your didn't turned it off via htaacess try using this form_open(base_url().'welcome/login_validation');

Answer (score 1):

Form open refers to the method in the `Welcome` Controller which will handle the Login Form.

In your view it is `echo form_open('welcome/form_validation');`

But

In your Controller it is `public function login_validation()`

Either change the view `form_open` action or `Controller's` method name

Comment: I am still getting the same issue, I have changed the view to say 'welcome/login_validation'

Comment: If you are using linux then the Controller's name is case sensitive

Comment: I am using Windows 10

Comment: also in your view use `echo form_open(site_url('welcome/login_validation'));`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97930/discussion-between-ddrossi93-and-murtaza-khursheed-hussain).